# Adding extra one email address who receives email as admin - woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

Is there any way for Adding extra one email address who receives email as admin.There are many ways I found but that sends cuatomar mail...but I need to send like a mail admin receives.This extral mail is variable.it changes on each orders

Answer (score 0):

You can add following code to function.php

```
update_option( 'admin_email', 'me1@example.com, me2@example.com' );
```

Change your email ids here which you want to add as admin email..

**OR**

go to wp_option table  in phpmyadmin, click on the admin_email address that is there, then add in your additional email separated with a comma (Not a semicolon).